# Trying to refresh the page in php but getting an error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

So, I have a file in a WordPress theme that has a piece of javascript in it which allows a user to upload an audio to Soundcloud. See code below:

```
SC.connect({
  connected: function(){
    $("#uploadStatus").html("Uploading...");
    SC.recordUpload({
      track: {
        title: "My Recording at The Appreciation Engine",
        sharing: "public"
      }
    }, function(track){
      $("#uploadStatus").html("<a href='" + track.permalink_url + "' class='sclink'>" + track.permalink_url + "</a>");        
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "MYPATHGOESHERE/record.php",
data: {
  url: track.permalink_url,
  name: track.name
}
});
    });
    }
});
```

Once the upload's done, the URL to the new track gets sent to another PHP page, which creates a new WordPress post with the URL of the soundcloud track as the post content. See code below

```
header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

// Create post object
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'My Appreciation',
     'post_content' =>
         $_POST["url"],
     'post_status' => 'publish'
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );


$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
$url = get_permalink( $post_id );
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

Now, the issue I am having is I need the browser to refresh to the new post that was just created in WordPress, but I keep getting the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load Cannot make any requests from null.".

Any ideas on how this can be done or if I have the redirect codes in the php wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are are calling `wp_insert_post( $my_post );` twice or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than redirecting inside of your PHP script that is called via AJAX, instead try echoing out the URL - then in your Javascript, take the results of the AJAX call (the URL) and perform a Javascript redirect.

Edit:

Update PHP code to:

```
echo $url;
exit();
```

Update JavaScript code to retrieve the URL and redirect:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "MYPATHGOESHERE/record.php",
   data: {
     url: track.permalink_url,
     name: track.name
   },
   success: function(data) {
       location.href = data;
   }
});
```

Comment: How would I send the URL result back to the javascript? I am a bit of a fish out of water when it comes to java/ajax so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Rather than `wp_redirect($url)`, just `echo $url`;

Comment: I just tried removing the wp_redirect($url) and change it for echo $url but it doesn't redirect the page.

Comment: I updated my post to include sample of catching the response and redirecting.

Comment: THANK YOU! This works and is saving the remaining hair in my head from being ripped out :)

Answer (score 1):

use header for redirection

```
header('Location:http://yoururl.com');exit();
```